# Enquires on visa expiration

Tags: schengen-visas, poland, ghanaian-citizens

I may like to know if I can travel back into the territory of Poland  3 days before my type D visa expires or the average number of days I have to be back in Poland before my visa expires

Comment: You’re going to have to give us more information if you want an answer. For example, your citizenship, what type of Schengen visa you have, how many days you’ve already spent in Poland in the last 180 day period

Comment: Am a Ghanaian and visa is multiple entry and have been in Poland for the last 180 days since my visa is still valid

Comment: A type D or C visa?

Comment: I have a type D visa

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can enter Poland up to and including the last day of validity of your type D visa.  You may be asked to show a credible plan to leave before it expires, unless you can show that you are planning to apply for a residence permit in Poland to replace the visa.  If you already have a Polish residence permit then you can enter on the basis of the residence permit without regard to the expiration of the visa.